# How can I resolve git merge conflicts by keeping my version of files that I changed?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two Git branches, `mybranch` (which is checked out) and `theirbranch`. I would like to merge `theirbranch` into `mybranch`, resolving conflicts by keeping my version of a file if I've changed it (i.e. it has changed on `mybranch` since the last common ancestor) and their version of the file if I haven't.

How can I do this in Git?

Two things that don't work:

- `git merge -s ours`: this keeps my copy of all files, even if I haven't changed them.
- `git merge -Xours`: this keeps non-conflicting hunks from `theirbranch` in files that I've changed; I want to ignore all hunks from `theirbranch` in files I've changed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution (assumes use of a Bash-like shell):

```
git merge theirbranch
git diff --name-only "$(git merge-base theirbranch HEAD)"..HEAD \
| xargs git checkout HEAD
git commit
```

It would be great if someone could suggest something shorter!

Comment: That's fine for getting your version of conflicted files (as long as there are no rename issues). An alternate method would be to read the index (`git ls-files --stage`) and note where there are stage 1, 2, and 3 entries for files, or to use `git status --porcelain` and read that, but these would be longer. Note that for scripting purposes you might want to use `git diff-tree` (a plumbing command) rather than `git diff` (porcelain).